# cant access WSDL on localhost(TOMCAT) from client of Web service

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf

I am trying to create simple web service HelloWorld in java. I create method HelloWorld. Then using CXF framework i genereate web-service and client. Server is tomcat. But when i try to access web-service from client i get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:90)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
at sk.fiit.bado.testws.klient.TestWSService.<init>(TestWSService.java:43)
at sk.fiit.bado.testws.klient.TestSEI_TestWSPort_Client.main(TestSEI_TestWSPort_Client.java:48)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
... 4 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8080/TestService/services/TestWSPort?wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/TestService/services/TestWSPort?wsdl
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/TestService/services/TestWSPort?wsdl
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1434)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
... 12 more
```

Im guessing it is something about WSDL file. Because i cant access it either. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Your stack already told you what went wrong. No wsdl file can be found:

```
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:8080/TestService/services/TestWSPort?wsdl'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/TestService/services/TestWSPort?wsdl
```

Comment: Unfortunately, a `FileNotFoundException` is not always caused by not finding a WSDL file. A FNFE can sometimes be caused by authentication or user-agent problems.